# Responsive iframe height based on child content scroll height

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, responsive

I wonder if I could do something with my iframe height so the iframe won't have any scroll bar. Is it possible to read the html scroll height on iframe from it's parent via jQuery? I believe this should be possible if the child source is coming from the same origin domain.

I've tried to read the child via console, and it shows the correct content height:

```
$('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body.clientHeight
```

[image]

But how I do to implementing it to the parents js, here's the code:

```
$('#responsive-toolbar ul li a').on('click',function(){

    var target = $(this).data('responsive');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    if(target == 'phone'){
        $('iframe').css({'width':480});
        newHeight =  $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body.clientHeight;
        $('iframe').css({'height':newHeight});
    } else {
        $('iframe').css({'width':640});
        newHeight =  $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body.clientHeight;
        $('iframe').css({'height':newHeight});
        }
});
```

Comment: Not clear if current code is working or not or what happens

Comment: i have never seen this syntax for `css`, have you tried either `css({'height':newHeight})` (1 param object) or `css('height', newHeight)` (2 params, key/value)

Comment: Sorry, I just re-edit the syntax. So in this case, I want the iframe showing the child content without any scroll bar when it's width changed via buttons.